# How to stack images horizontally in README.md

Tags: html, image, github, markdown

I want to stack images horizontally in README.md file on github.

```
<img src = "screenshots/tool.png" width ="200" />

<img src = "screenshots/world_flash.png" width ="200" />
```

This produces this effect:[image]

And I want them to be one next to another. How to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't put any new lines in between them.

```
<img src = "screenshots/tool.png" width ="200" /> <img src = "screenshots/world_flash.png" width ="200" />
```

Should do the trick, at least according to my quick tests.

Please, see Waylan's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49633290/how-to-stack-images-horizontally-in-readme-md/49634032?noredirect=1#comment86290281_49634032) below for additional information.

Comment: Note that this puts the images in the same paragraph, so they will wrap to the next line if they are wider than the containing block. However, as long as the sum of the images widths are less than the width of the containing block, this will work fine. For anything more sophisticated, you would need to venture into CSS, which GitHib prohibits.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's already been answered. But that didn't help me. I used markdown tables:

```
| <img src="screenshots/tool.png" width="200" /> | <img src="screenshots/world_flash.png" width="200" /> |
```